# Draggable not working after using jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-draggable

I'm creating a html builder for my project which including importing a template and edit via drag and drop. I used jquery's load() function to import template to my console page. But after the load function is completed,the draggable become undefined. This is the error i'm getting after load function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
```

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   enableDrag();
   $("#canvas").load("../collectionTemplates/apparel/index.html", function(){
        $('.element').draggable({
           helper: 'original',
           containment: '#canvas',
           tolerance: 'fit'
        });
        $('.element').find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();
        $('.element').resizable({
           minHeight: 40,
           minWidth: 50,
           maxWidth: 796,
           handles: 'e, w, s, n'
        });

    });
});
```

Where enableDrag() is initial function to give drag and drop to the tools. In that draggable is working perfectly. But if i call the draggable in callback of the load function it's not working. Anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Works fine at my side. Can you create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Pen](http://codepen.io/)

Comment: @vbrmnd i'm not used to jsFiddle or Pen. I tried to create on fiddle. But how can i load external file in fiddle?. When i tried to load a website its giving failed loading error.

Comment: are you re-initializing `jquery` on your `index.html` page? If that is the case then your previously loaded/initialized `jquery widgets` gets overridden and i think because of that only you are loosing them.

Comment: Yeah that's the issue. When removed the jquery from the html page i'm loading, the issue is solved. But is there a way that i can tackle this? Since im creating a template editor, i wont be able to change the scripts manually.